# Using css to create buttons that span horizontally but the button stays the size of the word

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an email template using HTML and CSS. I currently have "FROM" and "SUBJECT" under my header. 
I want to make both of these buttons that are only clickable if I click one or the other. Currently, I just have two buttons with a large width. But I want to have a button class and a span class which creates the space. My current code is below:

```css
.myBtnHeader {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}

.unread {
  margin-right: 1.25em;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <a data-role="header" class="btn myBtnHeader"><span class="unread"><u>FROM</u></span></a>
  <a data-role="header" class="btn myBtnHeader"><span class="unread"><u>SUBJECT</u></span></a>
</div>
```

If someone is able to help it would be amazing.
I want it to look something like this:

| BUTTON |     --------- span --------   |BUTTON|

Sorry for the lack of formatting

Comment: float:right for the second button?

Comment: could you make this clear " I want to make both of these buttons that are only clickable if I click one or the other"?

Comment: Sorry, I want to make two buttons: From and Subject. However, in my .css if i make width = 500px all it does it make the button extend longer than the word itself. I want to be able to create a space horizonatally between both buttons where i cannot click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a grid container and set gap between buttons with grid-gap.

```
.buttons-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}
```

[Check codepen](https://codepen.io/mironvitalie/pen/bGdGmWb)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, CSS Grid could be a good solution for you. However, rather than using grid-gap, I would go with an empty grid column that can be `1fr` wide (Take up all the extra space available). This would make it responsive to changes in viewport width or viewing it in different sized screens.

I recommend learning all you can about CSS Grid and Flexbox (Another useful tool). See these articles:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Checkout this codepen: 
https://codepen.io/juan-g-04/pen/PoqoyyY

Use your browser's developer tools to inspect the layout. On Mozilla Firefox you can highlight the grid or flexbox like so:
[image: Screenshot of Firefox developer tools]
(See the bottom part of the image where the tooltip is. And notice the pink lines highlighting the internal borders of the grid)